# JSTL tag is not shown in the html

Tags: jstl

another thing, i the jsp i had included the jstl, and messages.properties contains the below one.i call from the jsp using the messages.properties.

but the when i try to run, the tag is not showing..
it is diplaying like this.

> ???heading???
>
> ???greeting??? Tue Nov 27 10:33:12 SGT 2012

### messages.properties (\HelloSpring\build\web\WEB-INF\classes)

title=SpringApp

heading=Hello :: SpringApp

greeting=Greetings, it is now

### JSP code (hello.jsp)

```
<head><title><fmt:message key="title"/> </title></head>
```

```
<h1>Hello - Spring Application</h1>

<!-- <p>Greetings.it is now ${now}  </p> -->
<!-- <p>Greetings.it is now <c:out value ="${now}" />  </p>  -->

<h1><fmt:message key="heading"/></h1>

<p><fmt:message key="greeting"/> <c:out value="${model.now}"/></p>

<h3>Products</h3>

<c:forEach items="${model.products}" var="prod">

  <c:out value="${prod.description}"/> <i>$<c:out value="${prod.price}"/></i><br><br>

</c:forEach>
```

Comment: The problem is resolved now..

Comment: i got the problem being resolved by the below following steps.


1) in the springapp-context.xml (dispacher ), i add the below 

<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"> 
<property name="basename" value="messages"/> 
</bean> 

2) second, i placed the messages.properties file inside the /WEB-INF/classes. make sure that after clean and deploy the file stills exits.

Comment: 3) also add the below tag , if the problem still does not resolve                                                        <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">  
            <property name="defaultLocale" value="en_US"/>  
    </bean>